# Being able to overwrite release artifact without permission

Tags: maven, gradle, artifactory

today I met the following situation:

1. Publish artifact with non-snapshot version to artifactory maven repository
2. When I publish it again using maven-publish gradle plugin it gives me 403 back which is ok, but
3. When I publish the same artifact to same repo using `id("com.jfrog.artifactory") version "4.24.20"` gradle plugin it overwrites an artifact (and I can see updated last-modified time for it)

User's permissions for this repository are

- Read
- Annotate
- Deploy/Cache

Am I missing something, or it really shouldn't work this way?

Comment: Can you check if a user have any other permissions by navigating to the user page and checking the permissions in it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems due to a known issue [RTFACT-26398](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-26398) where plugin uses same rest call.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @sankar-dunga's answer:

The plugin uses a Checksum Deploy mechanism. This feature allows accelerating uploads by skipping uploading files that already exist in Artifactory.
The artifact does not really getting overridden, but only its timestamp changes - you can't change or delete an artifact without overwrite/delete permissions.

If you want to disable this feature you can set `minChecksumDeploySizeKb` to 0:

```
artifactoryPublish {
    clientConfig.publisher.minChecksumDeploySizeKb = 0 
}
```

For more information:

1. [Issue 341](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/issues/341)
2. [Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin#GradleArtifactoryPlugin-TheArtifactoryProjectPublishTask)
3. [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifactbyChecksum)